# Deactivate the ID (older Table)?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

I have an old table without an ID (without a primary key).

Now I have to insert a record via Laravel and I get an error message:

Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid ID position.

How can I deactivate the ID?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Log extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'oracle_client_nonprefix';
    protected $table = 'al_logs';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of your existing columns as primary key and disable auto increment

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Log extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'log_date';
    protected $incrementing = false;

}
```